# Why can't we allocate dynamic memory on the stack?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Allocating stuff on the stack is awesome because than we have RAII and don't have to worry about memory leaks and such. However sometimes we must allocate on the heap:

- If the data is really big (recommended) - because the stack is small.
- If the size of the data to be allocated is only known at runtime (dynamic allocation).

Two questions:

1. Why can't we allocate dynamic memory (i.e. memory of size that is
   only known at runtime) on the stack?
2. Why can we only refer to memory on the heap through pointers, while memory on the stack can be referred to via a normal variable? I.e. `Thing t;`.

Edit: I know some compilers support Variable Length Arrays - which is dynamically allocated stack memory. But that's really an exception to the general rule. I'm interested in understanding the fundamental reasons for why generally, we can't allocate dynamic memory on the stack - the technical reasons for it and the rational behind it.

Comment: Yes we can. `int test(int n) { int array[n]; }` is valid since C99. Oh if you're talking about C++, then variable length array is introduced in C++14

Comment: Memory-related RAII is actually about managing dynamically allocated memory through automatic storage duration (or what you call "stack") variable.

Comment: It would be better if you dropped this "stack" vs "heap" terminology.

Answer (score 7):

> Why can't we allocate dynamic memory (i.e. memory of size that is only known at runtime) on the stack?

It's more complicated to achieve this. The size of each stack frame is burned-in to your compiled program as a consequence of the sort of instructions the finished executable needs to contain in order to work. The layout and whatnot of your function-local variables, for example, is literally hard-coded into your program through the register and memory addresses it describes in its low-level assembly code: "variables" don't actually exist in the executable. To let the quantity and size of these "variables" change between compilation runs greatly complicates this process, though it's not completely impossible (as you've discovered, with non-standard *variable-length arrays*).

> Why can we only refer to memory on the heap through pointers, while memory on the stack can be referred to via a normal variable

This is just a consequence of the syntax. C++'s "normal" variables happen to be those with automatic or static storage duration. The designers of the language *could* technically have made it so that you can write something like `Thing t = new Thing` and just use a `t` all day, but they did not; again, this would have been more difficult to implement. How do you distinguish between the different types of objects, then? Remember, your compiled executable has to remember to auto-destruct one kind and not the other.

I'd love to go into the details of precisely why and why not these things are difficult, as I believe that's what you're after here. Unfortunately, my knowledge of assembly is too limited.

Comment: A small side note: you can indeed write `Thing &t = *new Thing()`, i.e., just dereference the pointer. That would leave the memory orphaned, but you could do it safely as `Thing *t_ptr = new Thing(); Thing &t = *t_ptr; ... ; delete t_ptr;`

Answer (score 6):

We can allocate variable length space dynamically on stack memory by using function _alloca. This function allocates memory from the program stack. It simply takes number of bytes to be allocated and return void* to the allocated space just as malloc call. This allocated memory will be freed automatically on function exit.

So it need not to be freed explicitly. One has to keep in mind about allocation size here, as stack overflow exception may occur. Stack overflow exception handling can be used for such calls. In case of stack overflow exception one can use _resetstkoflw() to restore it back.

So our new code with _alloca would be :

```
 int NewFunctionA()
 {
  char* pszLineBuffer = (char*) _alloca(1024*sizeof(char));
  …..
  // Program logic
   ….
 //no need to free szLineBuffer
 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Why can't we allocate dynamic memory (i.e. memory of size that is only known at runtime) on the stack?**

Technically, this is possible. But not approved by the C++ standard. Variable length arrays(VLA) allows you to create dynamic size constructs on stack memory. Most compilers allow this as compiler extension.

example:

```
int array[n];

//where n is only known at run-time
```

> **Why can we only refer to memory on the heap through pointers, while memory on the stack can be referred to via a normal variable? I.e. `Thing t;`.**

We can. Whether you do it or not depends on implementation details of a particular task at hand.

example:

```
int i;
int *ptr = &i;
```

Comment: What you did in the last example is referred to a stack variable through a pointer. I'm asking why we can't refer to heap memory through a normal variable.

Comment: @AvivCohn: Can we stop calling them "stack variables" please? It's a variable with automatic (or static) storage duration. If you need a concrete, practical, reason, then consider what happens when you fall into this trap: `struct T { int x; }; T* p = new T(); /* Is T::x "a stack variable"? */`

Answer (score 2):

Every variable that has a name, after compilation, becomes a dereferenced pointer whose address value is computed by adding (depending on the platform, may be "subtracting"...) an "offset value" to a stack-pointer (a register that contains the address the stack actually is reaching: usually "current function return address" is stored there).

```
int i,j,k;
```

becomes

```
(SP-12) ;i
(SP-8) ;j
(SP-4) ;k
```

To let this "sum" to be efficient, the offsets have to be constant, so that they can be encode directly in the instruction op-code:

```
k=i+j;
```

become

```
MOV (SP-12),A;   i-->>A
ADD A,(SP-8) ;   A+=j
MOV A,(SP-4) ;   A-->>k
```

You see here how 4,8 and 12 are now "code", not "data".

That implies that a variable that comes after another requires that "other" to retain a fixed compile-time defined size.

Dynamically declared arrays can be an exception, but they can only be that last variable of a function. Otherwise, all the variables that follows will have an offset that have to be adjusted run-time after that array allocation.

This creates the complication that dereferencing the addresses requires arithmetic (not just a plain offset) or the capability to modify the opcode as variables are declared (self modifying code).

Both the solution becomes sub-optimal in term of performance, since all can break the locality of the addressing, or add more calculation for each variable access.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the size of stack allocated memory must be known at compile time, because then the addresses of all variables on the stack van be encoded straight in the assembly (in terms of the offset from the SP), thus not having to do additional calculations at runtime?

Comment: Not exactly. The offsets of the variables in a given scope for each of the scopes (independently each other) have to be known respect to the base of that scope. The actual position of the "base" depend on the function call order, that is tracked run-time by SP.  It's not "all the stack all together", but scope by scope.   ...

Comment: ... You cannot know at compile time what the size of the stack will be since you cannot know the level of nesting the function call will have at run-time.  Neverless, the operating system impose a maximum value per thread to be known, to keep resource allocation towards processes under control. but that's just a limit, not a pre-computed value.

Comment: Btw the addresses of the variables on the stack are defined relative not to the stack pointer, but to the start of the stack, right? Because if we define `x` to be `SP - 4`, and then we add a new variable `y`, it would now be `SP - 4` and `x` would have to be updated to `SP - 8`. So it makes more sense to set the addresses according to the beginning of the stack, which stays set, not the top of the stack which constantly moves. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AvivCohn: It mostly depend on what kind of static analysis the compiler does: given a scope you know how many variables are there, and so you know how wide the required space will be. Counting backward from the end or forward from the begin does not change the run-time complexity.  But the origin is not the "beginning of the stack" but "the point where the stack is at the time the function is called" (But I think you intended just this, otherwise it will make no sense...).

Comment: ... But some compiler copy SP into HL, increment SP for each exiting variable, and access the variables as (HL+ofst). That's like what you said, using another register to address memory.

Comment: I am starting to think that our common myopia on optimizing assembly causes long time performance losses at high level...  I wonder how much  truth to this idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't we allocate dynamic memory (i.e. memory of size that is only known at runtime) on the stack?

You can with Microsoft compilers using [_alloca()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx) or [_malloca()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx). For gcc, it's [alloca()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variable-Size-Automatic.html#index-alloca-function)

I'm not sure it's part of the C / C++ standards, but variations of alloca() are included with many compilers. If you need aligned allocation, such a "n" bytes of memory starting on a "m" byte boundary (where m is a power of 2), you can allocate n+m bytes of memory, add m to the pointer and mask off the lower bits. Example to allocate hex 1000 bytes of memory on a hex 100 boundary. You don't need to preserve the value returned by _alloca() since it's stack memory and automatically freed when the function exits.

```
char *p;
    p = _alloca(0x1000+0x100);
    (size_t)p = ((size_t)0x100 + (size_t)p) & ~(size_t)0xff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most important reason is that Memory used can be deallocated in any order but stack requires deallocation of memory in a fixed order i.e **LIFO** order.Hence practically it would be difficult to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

*Virtual memory* is a virtualization of memory, meaning that it behaves as the resource it is virtualizing (memory). In a system, each process has a different virtual memory space:

- 32-bits programs: 2^32 bytes (4 Gigabytes)
- 64-bits programs: 2^64 bytes (16 Exabytes)

Because virtual space is so big, only some regions of that virtual space are usable (meaning that only some regions can be read/written just as if it were real memory). Virtual memory regions are initialized and made usable through mapping. Virtual memory does not consume resources and can be considered unlimited (for 64-bits programs) BUT usable (mapped) virtual memory is limited and use up resources.

For every process, some mapping is done by the kernel and other by the user code. For example, before even the code start executing, the kernel maps specific regions of the virtual memory space of a process for the code instructions, global variables, shared libraries, the stack space... etc. The user code uses **dynamic allocation** (allocation wrappers such as `malloc` and `free`), or **garbage collectors** (automatic allocation) to manage the virtual memory mapping at application-level (for example, if there is no enough free usable virtual memory available when calling `malloc`, new virtual memory is automatically mapped).

You should differentiate between mapped virtual memory (the total size of the stack, the total current size of the heap...) and allocated virtual memory (the part of the heap that malloc explicitly told the program that can be used)

Regarding this, I reinterpret your first question as:

> **Why can't we save dynamic data (i.e. data whose size is only known at runtime) on the stack?**

First, as other have said, it is possible: Variable Length Arrays is just that (at least in C, I figure also in C++). However, it has some technical drawbacks and maybe that's the reason why it is an exception:

- The size of the stack used by a function became unknown at compile time, this adds complexity to stack management, additional register (variables) must be used and it may impede some compiler optimizations.
- The stack is mapped at the beginning of the process and it has a fixed size. That size should be increased greatly if variable-size-data is going to be placed there by default. Programs that do not make extensive use of the stack would waste usable virtual memory.

Additionally, data saved on the stack must be saved and deleted in Last-In-First-Out order, which is perfect for local variables within functions but unsuitable if we need a more flexible approach.

> **Why can we only refer to memory on the heap through pointers, while memory on the stack can be referred to via a normal variable?**

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296228/why-cant-we-allocate-dynamic-memory-on-the-stack/26296301#26296301) explains, we can.

Answer (score -3):

Read a bit about Turing Machines to understand why things are the way they are.  Everything was built around them as the starting point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine

Anything outside of this is technically an abomination and a hack.